# data is not accessible in first page load Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a component and inside that, I have a **img** for showing profile image
I've put this in my html :

```
<img v-bind:src="this.profileSrc"/>
```

and in my **computed properties**, I have **profileSrc** method that is like this :

```
profileSrc(){
      const that = this;
      console.log(that);
      return `${variables.BASE_URI}/file/thumbnail/${that.$store.getters[types.AUTH_GET_USER].picture.id}`
    }
```

that works great from second page load but in first time, It crashes with :
**Cannot read property 'picture' of null**, it means that it doesn't recognize **this** variable at the first time.but when I change page and go back in my page again it's working.
why ?
thank you :))

Answer (score 2):

Check for the existence of `picture` in the computed property:

```
profileSrc() {
  const that = this;
  if (that.$store.getters[types.AUTH_GET_USER].picture) {
    return `${variables.BASE_URI}/file/thumbnail/${
      that.$store.getters[types.AUTH_GET_USER].picture.id
    }`;
  }
}
```

The computed property will "execute" as soon as `picture` is available for the component.

Comment: Agree with this answer, the picture state is most likely loaded asynchronously. Other option is to add `v-if` in dom template.

Comment: @JeremyWalters  unfortunately it gives me the same error, it's so weird because before the if condition I've put console.log(that); also console.log(that.$store.getters[types.AUTH_GET_USER]); in first log I can see from the output that picture is there but in the second log it gives me null

Comment: @HamidOsouli it is strange, have you tracked how the state gets modified by `vue devtools`. Check the state before the condition and after the condition. If you could replicate on codepen or somewhere would also help. I suspect it is definitely a race condition of sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `v-if` in `img` tag. In this case the picture will shown when the `pictureSrc` is loaded.

```
<img v-if="profileSrc" v-bind:src="this.profileSrc"/>
```

I agree with @Bennett Dams answer. I've just added some improvement. You don't need `that` and you can extract the picture into a variable.

```
computed: {
  profileSrc() {
    const picture = this.$store.getters[types.AUTH_GET_USER].picture;

    if (picture) {
      return `${variables.BASE_URI}/file/thumbnail/picture`;
    }
  }
}
```